# How to fix not printing any character and just count vowels and characters and read every character in a file

Tags: c++, logic, programming-languages

I just want to read every character in a file where I put characters from A TO Z but the program prints A every time and count vowels 4 and character 25 but expectation was to printing vowels 5 and characters 26 how to fix this program fixing from last 4 hours but nothing progress?
Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int i, count = 0, vowel_count = 0;
  string file_name;
  cout << "enter file name:";
  cin >> file_name;
  ifstream fin;
  fin.open(file_name);
  char ch;
  while (!fin.eof()) {
    fin.get(ch);
    cout << ch;
    while (fin >> ch) {
      i = ch;
      if ((i > 63 && i < 91) || (i > 96 && i < 123))
        count++;
      if (i == 'a' || ch == 'A' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'U')
        vowel_count++;
    }
    cout << "\n No. of Characters in a File : " << count;
    cout << "\n No. of vowel characters in the File  : " << vowel_count;
  }
  fin.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the outer loop?

Comment: You probably wanted to write this with a single loop.  As written, your outer loop reads and prints the first character.  Then your inner loop reads and counts all the following characters.  Try mentally stepping through your code line-by-line.

Comment: with single loop i got this result an extra Z   enter file name:file.txt
ABCD EFGHIG KL MN OP QR ST UV WXYZZ
 No. of Characters in a File : 27
 No. of vowel characters in the File  : 5

Comment: This may also be a good time to learn how to use a debugger. Try to observe the value of `ch` at each step of your program, and you will soon see where your character vanishes.

Comment: @irfanBaloch, Which of the loops did you remove? What is your current `while` condition? Remember, `while(!fin.eof()) { ... }` is always wrong. `fin.eof()` cannot tell you if the next read will succeed or not. It only tells you something about the last read.

Comment: can you give me direct solution I am really confused right now I remove while(fin>>ch) loop and modify loop while(!fin.eof() || fin>>ch) and get 1 extra character shows in output after that

Comment: Can I use this to read file  it give me no error but i don't know about this function properly that this will read character by chracter in text file or not char ch;      
  
        string file_name;
        cout<<"enter file name:";
        cin>>file_name;
        fstream fin("file", fstream::in);
        while (fin >> noskipws >> ch) {
    cout << ch; // Or whatever
}
        fin.open(file_name);

Comment: @irfanBaloch, Programming is not about trial and error. Nothing wrong about trial and error per se, but you have to understand why something worked, or didn't work. So in your code, what is the purpose of `!fin.eof()` and `fin>>ch`? And why do you `or` them together in the `while` condition? You really have to understand that part of your code to fix it. And before you tried to mash two loops into one, you should have tried to understand what was wrong with two loops in the first place.

Comment: What does `fin>>noskipws>>ch` do? You are allowed to make an educated guess in this case. And how does it affect the while loop condition? Answer that, and I'll be able to tell you if your code is correct or not.

Comment: I think this function read white spaces characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some really minor erros in the code, which I fixed for you.

Additionally, I added a check, if the file could be opened or not. That is the problem in most cases.

Please see below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int count = 0, vowel_count = 0;
    string file_name;
    cout << "\nEnter file name: ";
    cin >> file_name;
    ifstream fin(file_name);
    if (fin) {
        char ch;
        while (fin.get(ch)) {
            cout << ch;
            if ((ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') || (ch > 'a' && ch <= 'z'))
                count++;
            if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'A' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'U')
                vowel_count++;

        }
        fin.close();

        cout << "\n No. of Characters in a File : " << count;
        cout << "\n No. of vowel characters in the File  : " << vowel_count;
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n\n*** Error. Could notopen '" << file_name << "'\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```